# foreach query from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm trying to get log info for a google chart from two tables. Both have time stamps. When I do I'm getting the correct columns but the data from one table is all the same. (ts, mfz_temp & mfz_hum)

Both tables update every minute with the current time, temperature and humidity. They may be a few seconds apart. The times do not need to match right to the second but should be within a minute or two of each other.

```
 foreach($db->query("SELECT mfz.ts, mfz.temp, mfz.hum, mcl.temp, mcl.hum 
                     FROM mfz, mcl 
                     WHERE mfz.ts >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 HOUR) 
                     ORDER BY mfz.ts") 
                     as $row)
```

This is what I'm getting.

```
ts                  | mfz_temp | mfz_hum | mcl_temp | mcl_hum
--------------------------------------------------------------
2016-07-06 08:06:27 | 22       | 69      | 23       | 53

2016-07-06 08:06:27 | 22       | 69      | 26       | 49

2016-07-06 08:06:27 | 22       | 69      | 23       | 60

2016-07-06 08:06:27 | 22       | 69      | 25       | 51

2016-07-06 08:06:27 | 22       | 69      | 24       | 52

2016-07-06 08:06:27 | 22       | 69      | 26       | 46

2016-07-06 08:06:27 | 22       | 69      | 26       | 47

2016-07-06 08:06:27 | 22       | 69      | 25       | 49
```

Comment: You haven't put any join condition on your two tables.  You are asking the DB for rows from `mfz` that match your date condition, joined with ALL rows from `mcl`, and that's exactly what you're getting.  There is only one row in `mfz` that matches, and that one row is being joined together with all rows from `mcl`.

Comment: Been googling join and I got the concept but how do I join the date stamps if the two tables don't have identical times. Each logger can be up to 30 seconds off from the other. I would be happy if I could join the tables if the timestamps were within a minute of each other.

Comment: are the timestamps the only columns that link these two tables together?  They don't have any other overlapping data?  It's a bit unusual to want a query that pulls from two different tables when each table has completely unique data that's not shared with the other.

If that's the case, you'd have to do something along the lines of `ON TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, mfz.ts, mcl.ts) < 60`

Comment: `SELECT mfz.ts, mcl.ts, mfz_temp, mfz_hum, mcl_temp, mcl_hum FROM mfz join mcl ON TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, mfz.ts, mcl.ts) < 60 WHERE mfz.ts >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 20 MINUTE) ORDER by mfz.ts desc`
Didn't work. I thought if I could strip the seconds off the datetime stamps then I could do
    `ON mfz.ts = mcl.ts`
but can't figure out how to strip the seconds in a query